# how to call multiple function on each value of select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

here is my code. I want to call  `showdefault`()  function on every option value of select box and `MaxSize`() when value == "Address" and 
`EnableRangeSearch`() when value == "Checkbox". I am enable to perform this. Can any one suggest where i am wrong

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("select").change(function(){
                if(document.getElementById("data_type").value=="Address"){
                  //MaxSize() is function defined in function.php page
     MaxSize();
                }
              if(document.getElementById("data_type").value=="Checkbox"){
                  //EnableRangeSearch() is function defined in function.php page
                    EnableRangeSearch();
                }
        });
    });
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="data_type" id="data_type"> 
  <option value="Text Fields" id="TextFields">Text Fields</option>
  <option value="Address" id="Address">Address</option>
  <option value="Checkbox">Checkbox</option>
  <option value="Currency">Currency</option>
</select>

<?php include  'function.php'; 
        //fields is a class name
  $qwerty=new fields;
  $qwerty->showdefault();
?>
```

Comment: Where are `MaxSize` , `EnableRangeSearch` defined ?

Comment: In another page named 'function.php'

Comment: Try defining `MaxSize` , `EnableRangeSearch` within `.ready()` handler

Comment: use this 
$("#data_type").on("change", function () {    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create function for all select options then call `showdefault`() function in which you call selected option's functions. For example: see below

```js
//this script for sending `id` of dropdown option to results.php page
$('#data_type option').on('click', function(){
$.get('miniresults.php', 
  {
 option: this.id 
  },
function(data){
 $('.show_contain').html(data); //do something with whatever data is returned
 });
});
```

```html
IN home.php
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" name="apply" id="apply" method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Data type</label>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
  <select class="form-control" name="data_type" id="data_type"> 
   <option value="Text_Fields" id="TextFields">Text Fields</option>
   <option value="Address" id="Address">Address</option>
   <option value="Checkbox" id="Checkbox">Checkbox</option>
   <option value="Currency" id="Currency">Currency</option>
  </select>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Field Name</label>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="FieldName" placeholder="Field Name">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="show_contain" id="show_contain">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Display Label</label>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="DisplayLabel" placeholder="Display Label">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>

IN miniresults.php
<?php
class fields
{
 public function showdefault()
 {
  $viewdefault='<div class="form-group"><label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Display Label</label><div class="col-xs-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="DisplayLabel" placeholder="Display Label"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-xs-3 control-label">System Label</label><div class="col-xs-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="SystemLabel" placeholder="System Label"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Help Text</label><div class="col-xs-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="HelpText" placeholder="Help Text"></div></div>';
  return $viewdefault;
 }
 public function get_default_value()
 {
  $set_default_vals='<div class="form-group"><label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Default Value</label><div class="col-xs-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="DefaultValue" placeholder="Default Value"></div></div>';
  return $set_default_vals;
 }
 public function get_msize()
 {
  $addr="<div class='form-group'><label class='col-xs-3 control-label'>Max Size</label><div class='col-xs-6'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='MaxSize' placeholder='Max Size' value='255'></div></div>";
  return $addr;
 }
 public function get_range()
 { 
  $range="<div class='form-group'><label class='col-xs-3 control-label'>Enable Range Search</label><div class='checkbox col-xs-6'><label><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='EnableRangeSearch' value='Yes' /></label></div></div>";
  return $range;
 }
}
//this class for different datatypes
class drop_type extends fields
{
 function show_Text_Fields()
 {
  echo $this->showdefault();
  echo $this->get_default_value();
  echo $this->get_msize();
 }
 function show_Address()
 {
  echo $this->showdefault();
  echo $this->get_default_value();
  echo $this->get_msize();
 }
 function show_Checkbox()
 {
  echo $this->showdefault();
  echo $this->get_default_value();
 }
 function show_Currency()
 {
  echo $this->showdefault();
  echo $this->get_default_value();
  echo $this->get_range();
 }
}
//Object declaration of class drop_type()
$show_drop = new drop_type();

//$_GET['option'] contain `id` of dropdown option
switch($_GET['option']){

//case include name of options in dropdown
    case 'TextFields':
  echo $show_drop->show_text_fields();
        break;
    case 'Address':
  echo $show_drop->show_Address();
        break;
    case 'Checkbox':
        echo $show_drop->show_Checkbox();
        break;
 case 'Currency':
        echo $show_drop->show_Currency();
        break;
  default:
  //default contain textfields contain
  echo $show_drop->show_text_fields();
        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $("#data_type").change(function () {
        showdefault();
        if ($(this).val() == "Address") {
            MaxSize();
        } else if ($(this).val() == "Checkbox") {
             EnableRangeSearch();
        }

    });
```

you need define javascript function for   showdefault(), MaxSize() and EnableRangeSearch().